# Replace a random letters in a string with a matching one

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace letter or letters in a string with a matching letter but I want it to be random.

`$string = "This is random text in this string.";`

Here are a few examples of letter I would change below
`s = $`,`o = 0`,`i = l`

I'm trying to randomly replace letters in that string above and the output would look like this below. It would be all random and wouldn't need to change all the letters just a few at random that match the letters above.

Output Examples

`This is rand0m text in this $tring.`

`Thi$ is random text in this string.`

How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: What have you tried? [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Probably just use str_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Mike I does not want to replace **all** occurences. Just a few.

Comment: Which ones? How do you decide? If at random, then how many?

Comment: I've found a few example on stackoverflow but all they do is randomly replace letters with a preset letter instead of replace it with a matching letter. If the random letter selected doesn't have a replacement it can ignore it and not replace it. @TiMESPLiNTER is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't get any more random than this. add to the array $a for more replacement characters

```
$str = 'This is random text in this string.';
$str2 = '';

function repl($char){
    $arr = array(
        's' => '$',
        't' => 'T'
    );

    foreach($arr as $key=>$a){
        if($char == $key) return $a;
    }
    return $char;
}


foreach(str_split($str) as $char){
    if(!rand(0, 9))     $str2 .= repl($char);
    else                $str2 .= $char;

}

echo $str."\n";
echo $str2;
```

Comment: @chillers You can change the randomness as well by messing around with the rand(0,1) values, a positive number will change the character, a negative number will not change the character, e.g. rand(-8, 1) means that there is a 90% of the character not being changed.

Comment: I tried -8 and it almost changes all the letters each time. I even tried + numbers and it seems it wants to change all them on each output load.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
$string = "This is random text in this string.";

$replace = array('s' => '$', 'o' => '0', 'i' => '1');
foreach(array_rand($replace, (count($replace)/2)+1) as $key) {
    $string = str_replace($key, $replace[$key], $string);
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb25c967a6533a4a3e5e8cae57e1f55404ba5195).

Comment: Getting a `invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what you want to do. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you need anything else please ask